# What to do immediately after informing the journal's managing editor that you are withdrawing your paper submission in their journal?

Tags: publications, peer-review, paper-submission, journal-workflow

After waiting for 7 months (and counting), I decided to withdraw my paper submission to a particular journal. The reasons are as follows:

1. The review decision for a particular paper is to be made within six months after they received the paper. However, in my case, it has been 7 months since they acknowledged that they received my paper.
2. A week before the 6 months of review period, I sent an e-mail to the journal's managing editor about the status of my submission. After 21 days, I did not receive any response. That is why
3. I sent another e-mail to the journal's managing editor about the status of my submission and I included in the e-mail that If I did not receive any reply for a period of 1 week, I will withdraw my submission.
4. After 9 days, I still did not receive any reply.

So, I decided to withdraw my paper submission via e-mail.

My questions are: (1) Is my decision correct? (2) What should I do after informing the journal's managing editor that I am withdrawing my paper submission? (3) Shall I wait for the managing editor to acknowledge that he/she received my withdrawal submission e-mail? (4) Shall I submit my paper to another journal?
Your answers Sirs/Mams will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What country are the people you're corresponding with from?  There are some big problems in the world right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Waiting for them seems like a lost cause. Unless you have signed some release or given them copyright, the paper is yours. You can submit it as you like.

But submitting it *minutes* after notifying them of a withdrawal might be hasty. A few days wait is suggested. But they don't seem to have a very good record of corresponding with authors.

Comment: Thanks Dr. @Buffy for the kind answer. Given that they do not have a very good record of corresponding with authors, about how many days shall I wait before submitting the paper in another journal?

Comment: I would think a week would be plenty.But note that these are not normal times. They may actually be totally shut down due to the pandemic.

Comment: Thanks again Dr. @Buffy. I will wait for another week. Will also consider the reality that this time is not a normal time.